# Differentiating between Prins reaction / ene reaction experimentally

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, pericyclic

The Prins reaction – stepwise addition of an alkene to a carbonyl compound – leads to the same product as a concerted ene reaction. This is illustrated here with tin tetrachloride as a Lewis acid, which (as far as I know) lowers the activation energy of both pathways:

[image: Mechanistic pathways of Prins and ene reactions]

*How can these two mechanistic pathways be differentiated experimentally?*

One thing that I can think of right now would be the stereochemistry of the alkene formed - presumably in a concerted pathway, the cyclic transition state (envelope-like, if I remember correctly?) the substituent R' would be positioned equatorial or pseudo-equatorial. However, I'm not confident enough to undertake an analysis of the stepwise reaction.

I'm open to hearing about other possibilities, e.g. kinetic studies or spectroscopic studies. I suppose the free carbocation in the Prins reaction could lead to a more negative coefficient $\rho$ in a Hammett analysis, compared with a stepwise mechanism?

I'd also be glad if somebody could provide an example in the literature, if it exists. (I confess to not having looked this up - been very busy.)

Comment: Determine the kinetic isotope effect for the $\ce{C-H}$ bond that is broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The traditional Prins reaction was run in aqueous acid (H<sub>2</sub>SO<sub>4</sub>, HCl) with formaldehyde. The carbocation formed by addition of the alkene was trapped by a nucleophile, or if E<sub>1</sub> elimination occurred, the most stable alkene formed. The Lewis acid-catalyzed ene reaction is intramolecular without nucleophile capture and the less stable alkene is formed, at least when an isopropenyl group is present in the reactant. Two examples follow:

[image]

Malonaldehyde **1**, which has two enantiotopic aldehyde groups, reacts via transition state **2** to produce alcohol **3** as the major product. The cyclopentadiene ring is in effect a t-butyl group that prefers being equatorial in the transition state. Note the exocyclic double bond as opposed to a more stable endocyclic position. The hydroxyl group is axial. Aldehyde **4** follows the same type of pattern forming axial alcohol **5**. If an open transition state were operable, the equatorial alcohol would be anticipated.
[PS: You can Google much of this information.]

1) *J. Am. Chem. Soc.*, **1990**, *112*, 2149-2158

2) *J. Am. Chem. Soc.* **1984**, *106*, 718-721

Comment: I probably think it does answer the question. The main point is that the transition state for a cyclic mechanism leads to different stereocontrol.